# React: passing mapped data from button onclick to display on another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm having some difficulty passing data that I have mapped from an API, it displays a bunch of Event cards based on how many events there are in the API array.

This my Event Cards component;

```
export default function EventCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios("http://localhost:23455/Event");
    setData(result.data);
  };
  fetchData();
  }, []);

 const handleClick = (value) => () => {
   console.log(value);
 };

return (
 <div>
  <Row>
    {" "}
    {data.map((item) => (
      <Card
        className={classes.root}
        style={{ marginRight: "25px", marginBottom: "25px" }}
      >
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
              {item.icon}
            </Avatar>
          }
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="settings">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
          title={item.name}
          subheader="September 14, 2016"
        />
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={LordsLogo}
          title="Paella dish"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            <p key={item.id}> {item.description}</p>
            <p key={item.id}> {item.startDate}</p>
            <p key={item.id}> {item.endDate}</p>
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <Button variant="outlined">Steward</Button>
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick({ item })}>
              Tickets
            </Button>
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    ))}
  </Row>
</div>
);
}
```

I have an onclick function which logs what data is being added into "value" onclick, if I click a card, the console log the value of that specific card: [image]

What I'm trying to do now is use this information in another component called ServiceForm. I want to be able to click the button, be linked to ServiceForm, and use the variables within "Item" in the ServiceForm component, Ideally as shown below;

```
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridForeName">
          <Form.Label>**{item.description}**</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
```

EventCard if a functionalComponent and ServiceForm is a class based component, how could I pass the information from the first to the latter? Thanks

Edit: To show component hierarchy

ServiceForm is rendered in ServiceApplication, as shown:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ServiceForm } from "../components/ServiceForm";

class ServiceApplication extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
      &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <h1>Service Application</h1>
      &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <h6>Users can use this page to apply for tickets.</h6>
      &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <ServiceForm />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

export default ServiceApplication;
```

EventCard component is rendered in EventsPage, as shown below;

```
import EventCard from "../components/EventCards/EventCard";

class EventsPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <h1>Events</h1>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <h6>
          Welcome to the Events, here you can apply for seats or tickets at the
      events shown below.
        </h6>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <Row>
          <EventCard />
        </Row>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  } 
}

export default EventsPage;
```

The idea is to pass on the ID when Clicking the 'Tickets' button on the EventCard (the ID is being pulled from an API and mapped).

Comment: onClick={handleClick({ item })} change to onClick={() => handleClick({ item })}

Comment: Please mention hierarchy, whether ServiceForm a child component or a parent?

Comment: @Roy.B I changed that, however nothing is logged onclick now

Comment: @devd ServiceForm would be the parent component i suppose

Comment: Please share the full flow , then we will be able to answer accurately.

Comment: @devd So i should include the ServiceForm code here also?

Comment: Yes, where ServiceForm is rendered and where your second component is rendered.

Comment: @devd Done, I have included the code where both components are rendered

Comment: It looks like both the components are independent of each other. You will have to use redux to achieve your goal.

Comment: Should probably clarify that Redux is one possible solution, of which there are many to solve this data access problem. You do not *have* to use Redux.

Comment: agreed and the useContext hook is a good alternative to redux...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of how you want to store state in your app really.

Take a simple example where a component which is a child of another. In that case, the parent can store the state locally e.g. useState() and pass it down as props to the child.

```
const SomeParent = () => {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = React.useState(true)
  return (
    <Child isTrue={isTrue} />
  )
}
```

There may be cases where you want to share state across multiple components, or across your whole app. In that case, you have a load of different options.

**1. Lifting state up to the highest point you need.**

It would be easiest to move your state which is shared between multiple components up to the highest point that the two components share.
e.g.

```
Section component <- store state here
  Parent one
    child one
    child two
  Parent two
    child one
```

Here you can again either useState() or alternatively store the state in a useReducer() and pass dispatch down.

The data flow would then look something like this:

1. initialise state in the section component e.g. const [someState, setSomeState]
2. pass the setSomeState callback down to the Parent component and in turn child component as a prop e.g.
3. In the child component set state onClick using the callback e.g. onClick = {() => action(item)}
4. pass the state value down to your second Parent component and in turn child component e.g.
5. You have access to the state in your form

This can be an object or multiple state values. As complexity increases, I tend to reach for useReducer().

**2. Implementing useContext OR Redux in your application** to create an application state accessible from any component (This is a much bigger explanation and there are lots of resources on each...

**NOTE:** I'm not sure why you're using two sets of brackets here:

```
const handleClick = (value) => () => {
   console.log(value);
 };
```

and when you're calling handleClick you need to switch it for an arrow function if you're passing a value:

```
onClick={handleClick({ item })

...

onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, you want to trigger a class component function from a functional component by passing item prop, if it was a parent child components you can pass a function as a prop and trigger it whenever you want from your parent or child component.

but in your case both components are not connected, what you can do without using redux is to create a public local storage for ex let's call it localStorage.js :

```
var PublicData = (function() {

  var data = null;

  var getData = function() {
    return data;
  };

  var setData = function(props) {
    data = props;  
  };

  var clearData = function() {
    data = null;
  };

  return {
    GET: getData,
    SET: setData,
    CLEAR: clearData
  }

})();

export default PublicData;
```

then you import it and use like the following :

```
import PublicData from './PublicData.js';

PublicData.SET(apiData); // you set your data once you fetch it 
const data = PublicData.GET(); // get data 
PublicData.CLEAR(); // clear your data
```

Note : this is not an actual localStorage, but it work the same, it will help you to share variables between your components.

Comment: I think suggesting you should write your own data storage function to do the job that useReducer or useContext are designed for is bad advice.

Comment: i gave two options, the first one is to send callback function as a prop to child component and trigger it from there, but nothing is connected so you have to share it in another way, and that will solve his problem even if its not the best solution, while you suggested to pass just a simple prop that won't solve it in every way, and then you downvoted my answer and can't even do the difference between localstorage and reducer or context ! and how is that a bad advice even if you think that they do the same work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const handleClick = (value) => {
 console.log(value);
};

<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => handleClick({ item })} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Parent
   /      \
Service  Event
```

I'm guessing from your question that a simplification of your app tree looks like the above.

The problem you are having is the following:

```
    Parent
   /      \
Service  Event
          Data
```

In a top down architecture Service does not know about Event and any data over there in the that branch.

So you have 2 options (likely more, but these 2 get you a long way):

1. Hoist the data

```
    Parent
     Data
   /      \
Service  Event
```

2. Store the data somewhere else and provide a mechanism for access

```
Data

    Parent
   /      \
Service  Event
```

**Option 1** can be achieved by passing props (the data) and functions (passed using props) to manipulate the data (or, indeed, populate it in the first place i.e. fetch it)

The flow would look something like:
Parent is stateful. Parent passes the current state of the data to children that care about it (in your case that looks like Service and Event). Parent passes a function to Event, which can be attached to a click handler within the Event subtree of elements.

Due to passing a function down, when that click handler is invoked it can set the state of the Parent, from which the normal top-down rendering flow will handle setting updates and passing the data changes down the tree, whereby they will (usually) invoke a re-render.

I think [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) uses this method, and it is becoming increasing popular once more as we look to split applications up and eschew global state management.

**Option 2** is where data management libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started), [Cerebral](https://cerebraljs.com/), [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) et al live. If you’re familiar with the publisher/subscriber pattern then you'll know how they work.

In essence, these libraries hold shared state for your application, such as the data you have here. They then (typically) provide a pattern for you to manage changes to the state (via a published event) and ensure that components that subscribe to that data receive the new state and update.

The 'discussion' here differs from option 1:
The click handler publishes an event, which, in essence, asks for some manipulation to the data. Manipulation occurs (or not), and subscribers are updated. In your case, the click would tell the centralised store/s (i.e. anything listening) to fetch the data, when it is done and the data is changed (from empty to filled) it lets all concerned elements (or, quite possibly, the entire application tree and leverage top-down rendering) know about it and they can do what they need to do.

Which option you pick is entirely up to you, they both have pros and cons.

Good luck thinking about your data, how you store it, and how you use it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you asked this question because this is a problem that has been faced and solved a lot of the times. Other contributors have written nice comprehensive answers so I'll keep it short.

#### 1. Move shared stated to a common ancestor.

This one's pretty straight forward but gets very hairy very quickly.

#### 2. Use Context API

You can use react's context API to move code responsible for fetching data to your context and use that data anywhere in your app without a lot of hassle. This approach is getting quite popular nowadays. [Take a look at this](https://dev.to/gloriamaris/implementing-state-management-using-context-api-and-hooks-in-react-36jk) and [here's a sweet library to help you get started](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sweet-state).

#### 3. Use a state management library (preferred)

You can choose to use any state management library you like to solve this problem. There are quite a few options, and `redux` is the most popular one and for a very good reason. It enables you in implementing separation for concern between your data and your UI, but is a bit verbose.

`Mobx` is also popular and has a good developer experience but I personally don't like that it enforces a certain style to your code.

If you're new to react and state management then these libraries could be really daunting. I'd suggest you start with [zustand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zustand). It's super simple and gets the job done. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Custom Event` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent. It is not the best practice but it work.In `EventCard`, when user click you dispatch a Custom event with payload is `item`, then `ServiceForm` will listener that event and store `item` as state. Working demo here
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-ec6gc

EventCard

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const item = {
      description: "This is description"
  };
  const event = new CustomEvent("customEvent", {
      detail: item
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Service Form

```
const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => {
    setItem(e.detail);
  };
  window.addEventListener("customEvent", handler);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("customEvent", handler);
}, []);
```